# Get SKProduct Price in USD instead of store locale price

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, nslocale, skproduct

There is no issue to use user's store locale price for `inAppPurchases`. But I need to get product price in `USD` for my personal statistics. Is there a way to get `SKProduct` Price in `USD` instead of store locale price?

```
SKProduct *product = [self productForType:type].price
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple will give only locale price. But you can get price from Backend. Whenever you change price for any InApp Purchase then set equivalent USD amount in Backend. Through API call you will get that details.